# Делители факториала

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Делители факториала**

По заданному натуральному числу N необходимо вычислить количество натуральных чисел, которые являются делителями N! (факториала числа N).
Например, при N=4, N!=4⋅3⋅2⋅1=24. Это число имеет следующие делители: 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24. Таким образом, искомое количество составляет 8.
Напишите программу, которая по натуральному N находит количество делителей его факториала.

> Ввод 4
>
> Вывод 8

```
n = int(input())
d=1
factorial = 1
while n > 1:
    factorial *= n
    n -= 1
numb = factorial
count_of_dividers = 2
for i in range(numb - 1, 1, -1):
    if (numb % i == 0):
        count_of_dividers += 1
print(count_of_dividers)
```

Программа выполняется долго...

Comment: Мой совет из прошлой ветки и тут подойдёт

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите кодом...

Comment: Между N! и N!/2 нет ни одного делителя. Одно это позволяет сократить поиск вдвое. Хотя задача решается вообще не перебором. Вчера тут был точно такой же вопрос. Ищите и обрящете.

Comment: На вчерашний вопрос дан ответ неверный.
Я искала. Поэтому прошу Вас помочь.

Comment: Вам не надо сначала вычислять факториал, а потом делители. Надо во время подсчёта факториала уже их выделять, а факториал вообще не сохранять, а только найденные делители.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from math import factorial

# Функция факторизации, то есть разложения на простые множители
def factor(n):
    res = []
    i = 2
    while i * i <= n: # Ищем только до корня из n
        if n % i == 0:
            res.append(i)
            n //= i
        else:
            i += 1
    if n > 1:
        res.append(n)
    return res

n = int(input())
if n == 1: # Факторизация единицы ничего не даст, обработаем её отдельно
    print(1)
else:
    primes = factor(factorial(n)) # Рассчитываем факториал и получаем все простые делители
    # Наш ответ будем умножать в процессе, поэтому 1
    # num отвечает за количество повторений актуального простого делителя
    # последний обработанный простой делитель, начинаем с первого элемента
    answer, num, actual, length = 1, 1, primes[0], len(primes)
    for i in range(1, length): # Начинаем с 1, тк 0 элемент мы уже обработали
        if primes[i] == actual: # Если такой уже был, то просто увеличиваем счетчик
            num += 1
        else: # Если это новый простой делитель
            answer *= num + 1 # домножаем ответ на инкрементированное кол-во одинаковых делителей
            num = 1 # Обработка происходит уже на новом элементе, учитываем его
            actual = primes[i] # Меняем текущий элемент
    answer *= num + 1 # Последняя обработка не попадет в цикл, домножим так
    print(answer)
```